# Npm local module development with Hot Reloading

Tags: npm, webpack-dev-server, npm-link

I'm building 2 npm packages that are dependent.

`Module A (package.json)`

```
"dependencies": {
  "module-b":"~0.0.1"
}
```

We use `npm link` to connect these two apps locally. Currently we need to run `npm run prepublish` on module-b to visualise the changes on module-a while running webpack dev server on module-a

**Question:** Is it possible for us to have hot reloading between the two modules. Like any changes made on Module B will reflect automatically on ModuleA?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find proper solution as well. However, I use a workaround which work very decent.

I created a bash script which run npm build for module b and then npm build & npm start for module a and point nodemon to watch for changes in module b and trigger the bash script.

Other possible solution is to work directly in node_modules/module b and set webpack to watch node_modules/module b see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/